# How can I set Make Path in Makefile VS Code extension from Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, makefile, vscode-extensions

I'm new on this Makefile thing, and I'm having some issues trying to install the Makefile Extension from the VS Code Marketplace.

First of all, I'm using VS Code to connect to a remote machine, with RedHat8 kernel. It uses makefile and it works perfectly on a linux terminal, but now we are trying to migrate to VS Code.

So I was searching and I found this [Makefile Extension](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/now-announcing-makefile-support-in-visual-studio-code/).

On the extension settings, I have my *Makefile Path* defined, and it works, but I have some problem with the *Make Path*, because it is expecting a *make.exe* kind but I don't have any, because it's a linux server.

[image: Makefile settings]

I know my make path is on `/usr/bin/make`, but it says it cannot find make path.

What should I put in there?

PS: Sorry for my bad english, and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to set the "**Make Path**" to anything, it should default to **`make`**.

By default the "**Makefile Path**" is **`${workspaceFolder}/Makefile`**, but you can change it to whatever is required.

If you have a separate build folder, then it's better to set the "**Make directory**" instead.

For example, Debian packages are built under `debian/build/main` so set the `makeDirectory` like this:

```
{
    "makefile.makeDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/debian/build/main"
}
```